# Don't know how to create ISeq from: Symbol (logging.clj:13)

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojure-contrib

I have tried using require to get external libraries into my working name space but I keep getting the error

"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: Symbol (logging.clj:13)"

Below is my code snippet.

```
(ns com.my.project.mytest
(:require (clojure [zip :as zip]
                 [xml :as xml])
        (clojure.contrib [logging :as log])))
```

Now the thing is I haven't changed anything in the logging library and my above declarations used to work before I changed machines. What could be wrong?

Comment: Do the different machines have different versions of Clojure and/or the logging library?

Comment: I copied the exact same version 1.1.0. I really can't figure out what is wrong. .

Comment: While this has nothing to do with your problem but clojure.contrib.logging is now clojure.tools.logging

Comment: When you say it has changed you mean for versions after 1.1.0?